# Java heap space error in using aspose ITable

Tags: java, aspose, itable

I am using Aspose for automating a ppt generation process after reading some CSV files:

```
ITable tbl = sld.getShapes().addTable(20, 49, dbCols,dblRows);
```

dbCols is 7 & dbRows is 15, but it is throwing:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Can someone suggest something? Does Aspose limit the number of rows on a particular table?

Comment: My heap size is also set to maximum in eclipse.

Comment: There should be no problem with 7 col and 14 rows. Can you try the sample code from http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/slidesjava/Creating+a+Table+from+Scratch+in+Slide and check if it throws the same exception?

Answer (score 0):

No, Aspose does not limit number of rows or columns on any table.
Using the Aspose.Slides API, you can add a table with 7 columns and 15 rows.

```
double[] dblCols = { 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30 };
double[] dblRows = { 20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20 };

//Add table shape to slide
ITable tbl = slide.getShapes().addTable(100, 50, dblCols, dblRows);
```

Where 30 is the width of each column, 20 is the height of each row; 100 and 50 are the x,y coordinates of top left corner of the table.

I work with Aspose as a Support Developer.